# Pure mathematics PhD fellowships for international students in the US

Tags: phd, mathematics, united-states, funding, canada

I am an Indian student that completed both undergraduate and masters degrees outside India. I am currently looking for PhD fellowships that might fund my pure mathematics degree at US/Canadian institutions.

So far I’ve only been able to find fellowships that are open to US/Canadian citizens, respectively, or for Indian students that completed their undergraduate degrees at an Indian institution. Unfortunately I am not eligible in either case.

I was wondering if there are any fellowships that are offered to students regardless of their citizenship, or regardless of their undergraduate universities, and where I might find them?

EDIT 1: Some fellowships I did come across were only offered to humanities students. Once again I am ineligible for this.

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking specifically for fellowships rather than other sources of funding?

Comment: Fellowships (scholarships without work requirements) are fairly rare in comparison with teaching and research assistantships (in which the student works 20 hours per week in exchange for tuition and a stipend.)  Many of these assistantships are available to international students.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I understand that. I was also advised to seek scholarships in order to help me focus more time on studying and research. It is not a necessity rather a want.

Comment: @BryanKrause as I mentioned in response to Brian, I am aware of other methods of funding, I would just like to learn more about scholarships/fellowships.

Comment: @Tars Got it. I think Buffy's answer pretty much covers it. We don't allow "shopping" questions here that would include things like lists of individual fellowships; there are very few available, and even fewer for non-citizens.

Answer (score 9):

If you hold a bachelors from an accredited institution, you would most likely be considered for a Teaching Assistantship or (less likely) a Research Assistantship. This includes almost all tuition and fees along with a stipend that is enough to live on (frugally).

Very few US students have fellowships with no duties. You've already noted almost all such fellowships are for citizens - and they are very rare. The occasional student might have funding from the home country.

TAs assist in the undergraduate teaching program, with grading, help sessions, and sometimes their own sections of elementary courses. Math departments, in particular, have a huge need for TAs since they teach a large number of non-major students in things like Calculus.

You don't even need a masters for US graduate admissions and in many fields almost all doctoral students have TA positions. You need to have facility with English, but, coming from India, that won't be an issue.

Note also that the entire system is set up to pace students with such assistantships through the system. You will probably still need to take a few courses (to pass comprehensive exams) and have to deal with the scheduling of those.

Comment: Thank you for that, I am aware of the TAships. I ask with the objective of possibly reducing some of the work load, once again, not as a necessity.